# Keyboard indicators always on

Tags: keyboard

I installed Elementary os 0.4.1 loki on my Sony SVE1513W1RB. First I encountered a problem when the system wakes up from suspend keyboard and touch pad won't work. Fixed this problem by adding `i8042.direct i8042.dumbkbd` into file `/etc/default/grub` into parametr `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`. Now when system resumes after suspend all keyboard indicators (caps lock, scroll lock, num lock) are always lighting up and are uncontrollable. Can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://lightrush.ndoytchev.com/random-1/i8042quirkoptions) you can see why the indicators don't work. It's caused by `i8042.dumbkbd`. If you delete that part the issue will disappear.

Also, checking [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/916465/ubuntu-17-04-keyboard-not-responding-after-suspend) I've found that using `atkbd.reset` instead of `i8042.direct i8042.dumbkbd` will make the keyboard and touchpad work without having the issues that you comment.

So, just change that line and don't forget to `sudo update-grub` and reboot.

Comment: Replaced `i8042.direct i8042.dumbkbd` with `i8042.reset`, but now keyboard does not work after suspend.

Comment: Can you try with `atkbd.reset`?

Comment: `atkbd.reset` works.

Comment: Good, so problem solved! I've already edited my question with the correct command.